# What statements does Linq to entities support?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

Does anyone know where I can get a full list of supported statements for linq to entities, this is statements that will be translated and run on the database...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use All, Any, Concat, Contains, DefaultIfEmpty, Distinct, EqualAll, Except, Intersect, and Union methods. For details please see: 
[Standard Query Operators in LINQ to Entities Queries](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb738551(v=vs.100).aspx)

For a broader perspective see : [LINQ to Entities](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb386964(v=vs.100).aspx)